# Get PID of focused window in wayland

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, wayland, sway

Is there a method to get the PID of the currently focused window in wayland?

I am using the [sway](https://github.com/swaywm/sway) window manager. Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 4):

[`swaymsg -t get_tree`](https://www.mankier.com/1/swaymsg) returns a JSON-encoded layout tree of all open windows. Generated JSON is quite large but it is easy to parse it with [jq tool](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/).

You can run this script from demnu to display focused window info:

```bsh
swaymsg -t get_tree \                                                                                     
  | jq '.. | (.nodes? // empty)[] | select(.focused==true) | {name, pid}' \
  | swaynag -m "Window Info" -l
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I should habe mentioned that `swaymsg -t get_tree` does not output the PID at the time of writing. Now this feature thankfully was implementet.

Answer (score 2):

This works with floating or tiled windows:

```
swaymsg -t get_tree | jq '.. | select(.type?) | select(.focused==true).pid'
```